# How can I stop the 'next page' loop at the last page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code runs fine and even loops through all the pages, but the problem is that it does not stop at the last page.
From 15 page onwards it runs in a continuous loop that is page 15 , page 16 again page 15 and page 16 and so on

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib
import requests, random

data =[]

def getdata (url):
    user_agents = [
      "chrome/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; Win64; x64",
      "chrome/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; Win64; x32",
    ]
    user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
    header_ = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=header_)
    flipkart_html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
    f_soup = soup(flipkart_html,'html.parser')
    
    for e in f_soup.select('div[class="_13oc-S"]'):
        
        try:
            asin = e.find('a',{'class':'_1fQZEK'})['href'].split('=')[1].split('&')[0]
        except:
            asin = 'No ASIN Found'
            
        data.append({
            'ASIN': asin
        })
        
    return f_soup

def getnextpage(f_soup):
        try:
            page = f_soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class": '_1LKTO3'})[-1]['href']
            url =  'https://www.flipkart.com'+ str(page)
        except:
            url = None

        return url

keywords = ['iphone']

for k in keywords:
    url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q='+k
    while True:
        geturl = getdata(url)
        url = getnextpage(geturl)
        if not url:
            break
        print(url)
```

output

- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=1
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=2
- 
- 
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=15
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=16
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=15
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=16
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=15
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=16
- https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&page=15

Note: Some keywords return even 40 pages.
example: 'mobile'

So, how can I stop at the last page even if the pages are dynamic.

Issue :

```
def getnextpage(f_soup):
        try:
            page = f_soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class": '_1LKTO3'})[-1]['href']
            url =  'https://www.flipkart.com'+ str(page)
        except:
            url = None

        return url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is your selection of the element containing the link to next page:

```
f_soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class": '_1LKTO3'})[-1]['href']
```

It swaps between `Next` and `Previous` what causes the issue. Please avoid using `findAll()` in newer code and use `find_all()` instead.

Select your element more specific e.g. `css selectors` and `:-soup-contains("Next")`:

```
f_soup.select_one('a[href*="&page="]:-soup-contains("Next")')['href']
```

In this case the loop will `break` until resting last page.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the print statement above the if statement, you'll see it's selecting page 15 after page 16

[image]

To terminate your loop, check for the existence of the next button; if it's not there then terminate.